# Should I be using a random slope? and are my random effects right?

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I am unsure of the random structure in my mixed-effects design, and a bit confused on whether is a cross design or a nested one.

My experimental design is between 2 groups (`AgeGroup`, n=30), all tested in 3 experimental conditions (`SocialCondition`: N, Com, Coop) and in each of these the three tasks were applied (`TestCondition`: Con, Inh, Swt). 60 children were tested overall. Reaction time and Accuracy was averaged between trials for each task.

My final model looks something like this:

```
Model <- lmer(RT ~ Task + AgeGroup + SocialCondition +
                   AgeGroup:TestCondition + AgeGroup:SocialCondition + 
                   (TestCondition | Subject/SocialCondition), data=data)
```

Should I have added more of the fixed effects predictors to the random slope? What happens if a model with random slope has a worst fit than a model with just the intercept?

I have been reading about it and the random structure mentioned is `(1|Subject)+(1|SocialCondition)` but I am not sure if that is completely right.

Comment: Social condition is Cooperative, Neutral and Competitive (social environments in which children were tested). Test Condition are the three tasks applied: Control, Inhibition and Switching.

Comment: So TestCondition and Task is the same thing? Please edit to make it consistent.

Comment: The most general model in your case would be `RT ~ AgeGroup*TestCondition*SocialCondition + (TestCondition + SocialCondition | Subject)`. You could form less general models by excluding some interactions and/or some random slopes, but this seems a reasonable starting point. The model formula that you wrote down does not make a lot of sense to me.